# stylesheet tag and imports

Tags: ee2, css, import, stylesheets

So I have an include template named '.head' in which I am calling my CSS like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{stylesheet=assets/styles-css}" />
```

I was referencing the rest of the styles via imports at the top of that file like this:

```
@import url(//full-path-to-the-next-stylesheet-0.css);
@import url(//full-path-to-the-next-stylesheet-1.css);
@import url(//full-path-to-the-next-stylesheet-2.css);
@import url(//full-path-to-the-next-stylesheet-3.css);
@import url(//full-path-to-the-next-stylesheet-4.css);
@import url(//full-path-to-the-next-stylesheet-5.css);
@import url(//full-path-to-the-next-stylesheet-6.css);
```

This was fine when this was a static site. However, in EE I was getting mixed results by it 'sometimes' loading the styles and other times not. (Mostly not)

I thought maybe it would be better to just bring them all into EE and let it manage all stylesheets. Now I have this:

```
/*---------------------------------
IMPORTS
-----------------------------------*/
@import url("{stylesheet='assets/css-0'}");
@import url("{stylesheet='assets/css-1'}");
@import url("{stylesheet='assets/css-2'}");
@import url("{stylesheet='assets/css-3'}");
@import url("{stylesheet='assets/css-4'}");
@import url("{stylesheet='assets/css-5'}");
@import url("{stylesheet='assets/css-6'}");
```

The problem with that is that I end up having to change the first to `{path}` rather than `{stylesheet}` to use the `{stylesheet}` tag for the @imports.

This also takes FOREVER to load.

Long question now shortened...

What is the best way of handling this? I would like to use the native stylesheet tag for caching reasons.

Thanks in advance.

EE v2.5.5 - Build Date: 20121220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For speed and clarity, I would keep your css files outside of EE and also not use @import. Look into [Automin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/automin) (which I have used) or [Minimee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/minimee) (haven't used, but great reviews), which should really speed up and simplify displaying your stylesheets.

For example, with Automin, you would use something like the following in your head (so to speak...):

```
{exp:automin:css
    attribute:type="text/css"
    attribute:title="default"
    attribute:rel="stylesheet"
    attribute:media="screen, projection"
}
    <link href="/css/core.css" type="text/css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection">
    <link href="/css/design.css" type="text/css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection">
{/exp:automin:css}
```